# Elasticsearch - undefined method `as_indexed_json'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm able to do the bare bones keyword search with no issues in my app using elasticsearch, but as_indexed_json isn't working apparently and I have no idea why. I'm following this [tutorial](http://aaronvb.com/articles/intro-to-elasticsearch-ruby-on-rails-part-1.html), and the section in question is almost halfway down.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional info. I'm pretty new to this, so I apologize if this is a really dumb question.

Rails console:

```
2.2.4 :011 > Term.first.as_indexed_json

Term Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "terms".* FROM "terms"  ORDER BY "terms"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

NoMethodError: undefined method `as_indexed_json' for #<Term:0x007fa6cd9a6408>
from /Users/emplumb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.5/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
from (irb):11
from /Users/emplumb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/emplumb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/emplumb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/emplumb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/emplumb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Model:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    as_json(
      only: [:name, :definition, :etymology1, :etymology2, :uses, :romance_cognates, :notes1, :notes2, :quote1, :quote2]
    )
  end

end
```

Comment: How you opened the console? means using which command?? @evanejin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on that tutorial i hope you opened the `irb` using `rails c`.

But open console like this `bundle exec rails c` and try again

Comment: Dang, that was easy. Thank you. Yes, I originally opened it using rails c...and now I've looked up bundle exec so I have a better idea of when to use it in the future.